# Act As Taggable On --Adding Tags to a Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tagging, nomethoderror

I want to add a bunch of predefined tags to a model.

I have added it to my params in the Controller:

```
def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:image,:title, :description, :styles_list)
end
```

I have also included:

```
act_as_taggable_on :styles
```

Now I am just trying to add the tags but in my console I keep getting the following error:
Tried `Photo.styles_list.add`

got

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `styles_list' for #<Class:0x007fa9ee74aac8>
```

then I tried `styles_list.add` as described in documentation https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/wiki/Add-Tags

but I still get the same error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Photo.styles_list.add` is trying to invoke the `styles_list` method on the `Photo` class. That is incorrect. The `styles_list` method is available on a photo object.

Create/find a photo object as follows:

```
@photo = Photo.new

@photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
```

Then a style can be tagged with the following:

```
@photo.styles_list.add("awesome")
```

See https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#usage for getting a better understanding of how the gem can be used.

Comment: So is there a way to predefined the style list for the whole class of photos for a select box?

Comment: This answer requires that OP manually includes the string "awesome" everywhere in his code.  This is a magic string and violates DRY